# Cannot retrive a value using WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I use .net in c# with mvc3. I have a Web.Config setting .

I would need to retrieve the value of `<add key="sitelocalization" value="en-GB" /`>.

With my following code I receive this error:

```
String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: name

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: String reference not set to an instance of a String.
Parameter name: name
```

at this line
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(localization);

---

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="sitelocalization" value="en-GB" />
</appSettings>


        string localization = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sitelocalization"];
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(localization);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(localization);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sitelocalization"]

Comment: I tries and I receive String reference not set to an instance of a String

Comment: make sure the value is in the app.config of the main project (the startup project)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Configuration.Configuration rootWebConfig1 =
                System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration(null);
            if (rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings.Count > 0)
            {
                System.Configuration.KeyValueConfigurationElement customSetting = 
                    rootWebConfig1.AppSettings.Settings["customsetting1"];
                if (customSetting != null)
                    Console.WriteLine("customsetting1 application string = \"{0}\"", 
                        customSetting.Value);
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("No customsetting1 application string");
            }




<appSettings>
  <add key="customsetting1" value="Some text here"/>
</appSettings>
```

Comment: This appears to be a simple cut-and-paste of the MSDN article. I followed that article and wound up here because I had the same problem as GibboK.